# My Dist file is not updated

Tags: javascript, angular, build, webstorm

I'm trying to create a 'Dist' folder with `"ng build..."` in Angular 4, but the file created is not updated (one month ago i could create an updated version, now don't). Why?

Comment: Please run `ng build --verbose…` - and report results (you may answer your own question) or add (relevant parts of) output.

Comment: Some files have [big] label. Could this be a problem?

Comment: @goltornate, not unless it's over 255 characters long. https://askubuntu.com/questions/166764/how-long-can-file-names-be

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can't really help you much as your question stands now.